# Can anyone help. I opened a maven project on Intelij but in my main class I cannot import java.util.List

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to import java.util.List in Java project with Maven build system on Intelij but cannot import java libraries, here is the error:  Cannot resolve symbol 'List'

when I open a new project with Intellij build system there is no problem importing java.util, the only problem is when open a project with Maven build system

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions using correctly this site.

Comment: Does typing `mvn test` at the command line (outside of IntelliJ) work?

Comment: @k314159 I have no idea what mvn test is. I am new to Maven

Comment: `mvn` is the Maven command. Does the project contain a file called `mvnw` in the top directory? If so, start a command line and type `./mvnw test` (if you're on Linux) or `mvnw test` (if you're on Windows).

Comment: @k314159 no, I have only maven-status folder in the target folde

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to unlink the Maven project by right-clicking on pom.xml then add Maven again